# Database size increase inside a transaction

Tags: sqlite, transactions, sqltransaction

I am using an SQLite database. I am inserting many rows in it, with insert statements inside a transaction.

However, I noticed (with step-by-step debugging) that before I commit the transaction, my database file increase in size, which means that some data have been inserted in it before the commit. And after the commit, it increases one last time, by a large amount (this one last thing is normal however).

Is this database size increase before the commit a normal behavior?

Comment: The data has to go *somewhere*; the important thing is that it is possible for the transaction to be either committed or rolled-back properly.

Comment: Doesn't it go to the log files?

Comment: No. The data goes into the data file. The transaction log records information so the transaction can be rolled back if it fails. If your application crashes, the SQLite engine will use the log to revert the changes of any open transactions next time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Well yes, thank you for your answers, but I cannot mark it as one, since it is just comments